# How to open a static file in views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a little issue with opening a csv file in my views.py

Have tried the following 2 things:

- Open the file while it is in the same directory.
- Open the file from my static folder.

None worked, the framework django is new for me.

The code i have right know is a easy one :):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import shopify_orders as sb
import csv

def csv_converter(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        f = open(orders_export.csv)
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)
        f.close

    else:
        return render(request, 'serviceapp/csv.html')
```

There are some tutorials explaining how to import csv data in models, but my csv file is a bit complex.

[Django directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DtvW.png)

Your help is apreciated !

Comment: The path to the csv file should be from the django project directory...

Comment: Is that the exact code? And how do you know it's not working, i.e do you get an error message or empty data set etc?

Comment: ERROR  = FileNotFoundError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'orders_export.csv' < with brackets ('') or not same error. Guessing because django.core doesn't search in the same DIR file first.

Comment: Hey Illusion, thank you for your response could you explain in some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should open the CSV.

```py
def csv_converter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = open('serviceapp/orders_export.csv')
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)
        f.close
```

Comment: Hey thank you, apreciate your help, now i can move on :).